# method to check nested transaction

Tags: java, naming, validation

So I am writing a method to check and throw if a new transaction is being made in another transaction.
I first came up with straight forward `checkNestedTransaction`, but this seems vague since I cannot see what this method actually do.(like, when does this method throw)

What would be the preferred name for this method?

I've considered following:

- `checkNestedTransaction`
- `requireNoTransaction`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I decided to use `requireExclusiveTransaction` for now